# Library capable of plotting Lat Long onto image and saving as a png/jpg?

Tags: java, tomcat, gis, latitude-longitude

I'm looking into the feasibility of having my Tomcat server create an image dynamically from a set of a satellite's longitude and latitude positions and overlaying this on a world map and then export the image as a png or such. Are there any libraries out there that do this (especially ones that people would recommend)?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're re-inventing the wheel.

You could use a WMS server (several work with TomCat though the default is usually jetty).
The WMS server (See: [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/) or [MapServer](http://www.mapserver.org/) for the most popular Open Source examples) can get data from your database and render it upon request over background imagery, i.e. your world-map, or maybe OpenLayers.

The WMS query can specify image size and file format. This may be a little overkill for what you want, but they're fairly easy to setup (GeoServer especially).

If you have further questions down this vein, https://gis.stackexchange.com/ will probably net you more domain-specific help.